Exactness of certain direct image functor.
Let $X$ be a quasi-compact and quasi-separated scheme and $i:\operatorname{Spec}\,A\hookrightarrow X$ an affine open subscheme. The morphism $i$ is a quasi-compact and quasi-separated, and thus by this Lemma, the functor $i_*$ is cocontinuous and so it is exact.
Then, if we take another affine open subset $U:=\operatorname{Spec}\,B\hookrightarrow X$, the intuition tells me that if we denote by $V=i^{-1}(U)$, then the morphism $i|_V:V\hookrightarrow U$ should be such that $(i|_V)_*$ is also exact, but I haven't been able to prove nor refute it (for example, by finding a good counterexample).

I will change the notation. You have two affine open subschemes $U,V \subseteq X$ and ask if the inclusion $U \cap V \to U$ induces an exact direct image functor. Notice that every affine morphism has an exact direct image functor, and under mild assumptions, which are satisfied here, the converse is also true by Serre's criterion for affineness. So it holds (precisely) when $U \cap V$ is affine. In other words, $X$ must be a semi-separated scheme:
A scheme is called semi-separated when it has an affine diagonal. Equivalently, the intersection of two open affines is affine. We have "separated" $\implies$ "semi-separated" $\implies $ "quasi-separated", and these implications cannot be reversed.
An example of a non-semi-separated but quasi-compact and quasi-separated scheme is the affine plane with a doubled origin, i.e. $\mathbb{A}^2 \cup_{\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}} \mathbb{A}^2$. (Notice that the affine line with a doubled origin is not separated, but it is still semi-separated.) The intersection of the two copies of $\mathbb{A}^2$ is $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, which is not affine.
And in fact, the direct image functor associated to $i : \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ is not exact: First, notice that $i_* \mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}$ for the structure sheaves (via a direct computation of the global sections, but this is also an instance of the algebraic Hartog's Lemma). Let $x,y$ be the two coordinates. The canonical homomorphism $(x,y) : \mathcal{O}^2 \to \mathcal{O}$ is an epimorphism of sheaves on $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\} = D(x) \cup D(y)$, but its direct image is not an epimorphism of sheaves on $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Then, was I wrong when I said that $i:Spec,A\hookrightarrow X$ induced an exact direct image? or is it an affine morphism?

Oups, yes, it won't be exact. A scheme is semi-separated iff every morphism from an affine scheme into it is an affine morphism.

But it is true that $i$ is a q-c q-s morphism (isn't it?) so I must have misunderstood the lemma from Stacks project (I am not really into derived functors)

Yes, $i$ is qc qs, since $X$ is qc qs. You can find the basics here.

I have been thinking about it, if it is true that $i:\operatorname{Spec},A\hookrightarrow X$ is a quasi-compact quasi-separated morphism, then $R^pi_*$ is a cocontinuous functor for every $p\geq 0$ by lemma 30.6.1 of stacks exchange.
In particular, it holds for $p=0$ and $R^0i_=i_$. Thus, $i_*$ is right exact and so it is just an exact functor...

You mean this? This just talks about filtered colimits. That's miles away from all colimits.

But all finite colimits are filtered, and thus the functor is still right exact.

No, that's absolutely not true.
